# I need to trim the payload using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am having a payload as below

```
<order>
    <ordernumber>1-123
    </ordernumber>
    <orderline>
        <linenumber>root
        </linenumber>
        <parentnumber>
        </parentnumber>
        <type>order
        </type>
        <actioncode>Existing
        </actioncode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <linenumber>x1
        </linenumber>
        <parentnumber>root
        </parentnumber>
        <type>Bundle
        </type>
        <actioncode>Existing
        </actioncode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <linenumber>xsub1
        </linenumber>
        <parentnumber>x1
        </parentnumber>
        <type>Bundle
        </type>
        <actioncode>Existing
        </actioncode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <linenumber>xsub2
        </linenumber>
        <parentnumber>x1
        </parentnumber>
        <type>Bundle
        </type>
        <actioncode>ADD
        </actioncode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <linenumber>xsub3
        </linenumber>
        <parentnumber>x1
        </parentnumber>
        <type>Bundle
        </type>
        <actioncode>Existing
        </actioncode>
    </orderline>
</order>
```

I want to keep only `orderline = ADD` and its parent order line as below

```
<order>
    <ordernumber>1-123
    </ordernumber>
    <orderline>
        <linenumber>x1
        </linenumber>
        <parentnumber>root
        </parentnumber>
        <type>Bundle
        </type>
        <actioncode>Existing
        </actioncode>
    </orderline>
    <orderline>
        <linenumber>xsub2
        </linenumber>
        <parentnumber>x1
        </parentnumber>
        <type>Bundle
        </type>
        <actioncode>ADD
        </actioncode>
    </orderline>
</order>
```

I tried using identity function but could not figure out the logic....
can you please help me 
thanks in advance

This what I have tried, but am unable to figure out how to get the parent line item of Xsub2 where `actioncode = 'ADD'`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/order/orderline[actioncode !='ADD']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="parent" match="orderline" use="linenumber" />

<xsl:template match="/order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ordernumber"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="orderline[actioncode ='ADD']">
            <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('parent', parentnumber)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```